# How to hide information on a website from search engines?

Tags: web-application, search-engines

I have a website with many pages.
There are few lines of text on one of these pages which should NOT be visible to search engines - it means no one should be able to find my website after searching for the information provided in these few lines.
How can I achieve that?

I was thinking to exclude this particular page using robots.txt but in this case, I'm telling everyone that this page is interesting. Also, I was thinking to paste this text as an image but then it may look strange on mobile.

Is there a solution for what I want to achieve?

Comment: You appear to have conflicting goals. Robots.txt will tell search engines not to index it. Who then would find the entry "interesting" that you *also* want to hide from?

Comment: What hoops are you not willing for visitors to have to go through? Authentication and CAPTCHA can do this.

Comment: "Text might look strange on mobile" - memes do this all the time

Comment: @schroeder FOR EXAMPLE - let's say I want to have my phone number on site because regulations asked that from me but I don't want that you can find my phone number using search engines and I don't want that by searching this phone number my page is found as a result.

Comment: And that's my confusion: who is this new party who you don't want to expose the info to?

Comment: This is starting to look like an X/Y problem. What is the problem you want to solve by "hiding" the page from search engines? Because it appears that you want to hide it from more than just that, and potentially, you want to expose the page to only a few people.

Comment: Use a random URL, and search engines will not be able to find it unless someone links to it. And only those who have the link can access it.

Comment: @schroeder FOR EXAMPLE - let's say I want to have my phone number on site because regulations asked that from me but I don't want that you can find my phone number using search engines and I don't want that by searching this phone number my page is found as a result.

Comment: Frankly, then, it seems like you shouldn't put that info on the page or put a "phone number" that you don't mind being exposed.

Comment: In your example, people looking at the robots.txt is not a threat.

Comment: You are going to have to define what your real problem is.

Comment: Obfuscation is one possibility: convert text to an image. But the problem is not clear. If privacy is the issue get a virtual (and disposable) phone number to list on your website, that is unrelated to your regular phone line.

Answer (score 1):

If you want arbitrary people, who you cannot predict or define ahead of time, to access the page, then it needs to be unrestricted. If you don't want search engines from indexing the data, then you need to block automated processes from accessing it. CAPTCHA is a standard method for doing that.

But that still means that any human visitor to your site could find the information, and you appear to not want that either.

So, you need something that blocks automated processes, and is not easily discovered by human visitors, either. A random URL can work for this, and when you need to expose the information, you provide a link to the random URL. Change the URL periodically.